# Retorno JSON Dando Erro

Tags: android, json, android-studio

Estou fazendo um serviço para pegar o retorno JSON em uma aplicação Android, até aí tudo bem, mas não sei aonde estou errando na hora de pegar o valor.

A estrutura do JSON é essa:

```
"entity": {
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Sucesso",
    "clienteModel": {
        "codigoCliente": 1,
        "nomeCliente": "ederson",
        "rgCliente": "448868",
        "cpfCliente": "11212444488",
        "dataNascimentoCliente": 614833200000,
        "emailCliente": "eder",
        "dataCadastroCliente": 1504666800000,
        "codigoEndereco": {
            "code": 1,
            "message": "Sucesso",
            "codigoEndereco": 1,
            "nomeEndereco": "teste",
            "complementoEndereco": "sxasdf",
            "estadoEndereco": "sdafasd",
            "cidadeEndereco": "sdfasd",
            "bairroEndereco": "sdasds",
            "numeroEndereco": 11211,
            "numeroCEPEndereco": "06851020"
        }
    }
},
```

Esse é meu método onde leio o JSON, quando tento pegar o codigoCliente ele não encontra, o que estou fazendo de errado? o code e a message eu consigo pegar a partir dos outros campos nenhum consigo pegar.

```
private ClienteSaidaDTO getClienteSaidaDTOs(String jsonString) {

    ClienteSaidaDTO trends = new ClienteSaidaDTO();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObjectConvertString = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject jsonObjectEntity = jsonObjectConvertString.getJSONObject("entity");
        //JSONObject jsonObjectClienteModel = jsonObjectConvertString.getJSONObject("clienteModel");

        ClienteSaidaDTO clienteSaidaDTO = new ClienteSaidaDTO();
        ClienteModel clienteModel = new ClienteModel();

        clienteSaidaDTO.setCode(jsonObjectEntity.getInt("code"));
        clienteSaidaDTO.setMessage(jsonObjectEntity.getString("message"));

        clienteModel.setCodigoCliente(jsonObjectEntity.getInt("codigoCliente"));

        clienteSaidaDTO.setClienteModel(clienteModel);

        trends = clienteSaidaDTO;
        //}
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("DEVMEDIA", "Erro no parsing do JSON", e);
    }

    return trends;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É porque o "codigoCliente" esta dentro do array "clienteModel", então você deve pegar primeiro o array "clienteModel".

```
String[] clienteModel = jsonObjectEntity.getStringArray("clienteModel");
```